# Trouble with MongoDB insert

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, database

Currently using MEAN in order to connect my AngularJS app to a database.

I have a button called "commit to database" that first clears the mongodb database, then inserts my array of data (stored in $scope.filterTable) into the database.

I then have a button called "load from database" that updates $scope.filtertable to match data from the database.

Half of the time when I click the "commit to database" button, my database is empty. Half of the time, it's filled with the data I expect it to have.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Here's the code in my main AngularApp:

```
var commitToDatabase = function(){
    deleteDatabase();

    insertDatabase();
}

var insertDatabase = function(){
    $http.post("/AngularApp", $scope.filterTable).success(function(response){
        $http.get('/AngularApp').success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
}

var deleteDatabase = function(){
    $http.delete('/AngularApp');
}

var loadFromDatabase = function(){
    $http.get('/AngularApp').success(function(response) {
        $scope.filterTable = response;
    });
}
```

Here's the code in my server.js file:

```
var express = require("express");
var mongojs = require("mongojs");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");


var app = express();
var db = mongojs("AngularApp",  ["AngularApp"]);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/AngularApp', function (req, res) {
    console.log('I received a GET request');
    db.AngularApp.find(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);

        res.json(docs);
    });
});


app.post('/AngularApp', function (req, res) {
    console.log("POST");
    console.log(req.body);
    db.AngularApp.insert(req.body, function(err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});

app.delete('/AngularApp', function(req, res){
    db.AngularApp.remove({},function(err, doc){
        res.json(doc);
    });
});


app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running on point 30000");
```

Comment: We can safely assume you have tried looking for errors?  `if (err){ console.log(err);}`. I have to ask since you don't even mention if you reach your endpoint when your insert fails (does `console.log("POST");` trigger?) . Also perhaps you could show your `req.body` from when the insert fails, if you get that far?

Comment: You should also output your $scope.filterTable in your client just before posting it to make sure it has the expected data.

Comment: Oh, I think I see something now. You seem to have a request race between `deleteDatabase();` and `insertDatabase();`. Wait for a success on your delete before you insert.

Comment: That was it ippi. Thank you so much.